# is it possible to intercept Android 12 SSL traffic for specific apps?

Tags: data-monitoring, android-12

I am interested in a way to sniff/decrypt outbound SSL traffic from my mobile device running Android 12. One of the apps stopped working over mobile data recently and I am trying to submit a quality investigation ticket for my carrier to follow by providing endpoints and ports.

I found ways to do it before Android 7, but apparently a lot of security changes completely invalidated them.

Comment: As long as the app is not created by your mobile manufacturer it should be enough to sniff the encrypted traffic to see what is going wrong. You should be able to capture data e.g. using PCAP remote app with disable Mitm/SSL interception.

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I generate a PKCS12 CA certificate for use with Packet Capture?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226744/44325) (tested on Android 11, not yet confirmed on Android 12)